# GWT library override default theme

Tags: css, gwt

Currentlty my GWT app uses the default CSS Style ('com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'). 
When I've added the gwt-gantt library a lot of styles of GWT components (i.e. CellTable,...) have been overrided.
Is there a possibility to use this library without lost default theme?

Answer (score 2):

[GWT-gantt](https://github.com/waynedyck/gwt-gantt) Seems not maintained, with the most recent change dating 3 years ago.

I would strongly suggest you to [pick](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/) [any](https://jsganttimproved.github.io/jsgantt-improved/) [JS](http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/) [gantt](http://thegrubbsian.github.io/jquery.ganttView/example/index.html) [library](https://gantt.twproject.com/) [and](https://javascript.daypilot.org/gantt/) interact with it using JSInterop. This way you will have a wider choice of libraries and no style issues.

I know that this does not really answer your question, but I believe in the long term you will be better of with this approach.

Comment: You're right. I've used this lib because I'm new with GWT and I have no experience with JS lib wrapper. I'm try to follow the examples that you have suggested to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if gwt-gantt uses the same css style name in their component with the one used by the GWT component.

For example, GWT CellTable use ".cellTableEvenRow" for one of its CSS style name. If gwt-gantt use the same CSS style name, then the default CSS style can get affected.

So, check if gwt-gantt uses any CSS style name that GWT uses.

Comment: Yes. External lib uses CSS style that GWT uses. Is there any method to override CSS lib Style?

Answer (score 0):

Add css style name to the css style name used in gwt-gantt. This solution requires you to look into the css source code of gwt-gantt. 
For example: 
(1) Suppose gwt-gantt uses "gwt-Button" for its css style. Add "gantt" to "gwt-Button" in gantt's CSS style:

```
.gantt .gwt-Button{ 
/*CSS style used by gwt-gantt component*/
}
```

(2) add  element with "gantt" to enclose the gantt component:

```
<div class="gantt">

<gantt:component>
</gantt:component>

</div>
```

this method will cause the gwt-gantt css style applies only to gantt:component only, not to gwt component

Comment: I've tried this solution but the library always looking for its internal CSS

Answer (score 0):

it can happen if the gantt component add the style using other method. check the html source code about how the CSS style is added to the component:

(1) `<div class="stylename"></div>`

(2) `<div class="stylename" style="width:50% !important;"></div>`